# Angular testing button with shadow dom DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, shadow-dom

I have a simple component and I am trying to test the functionality of a button.  The element renders with a shadow dom element that contains the `<button>`.  In my test, I can access the `shadowRoot` however when I try to query that `shadowRoot` it returns null.

```
describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(), TransparentHeaderScrollModule,]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  describe('with default props', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })

    it('should emit when dismissed clicked', async () => {
      spyOn(component.handleDismissClick, 'emit')
      customElements.whenDefined('ion-button').then(() => {
        const headerElement = fixture.debugElement
        const ionButton = headerElement.query(By.css('.submitButton')).nativeElement as HTMLElement

        // displays the <ion-button> element
        console.log('ionButton', ionButton) 
        const root = ionButton.shadowRoot

        // see image below
        console.log('shadowRoot', root, root.host, root.querySelector('button')) 
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Why can't I access the `<button>` element?

[image]

Comment: can you create a stackblitz that recreates this issue? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13?file=README.md

Comment: Sorta... here ya go: https://ionic6-angular13-mdwxo2.stackblitz.io